# Reference to temporary returned from a function

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I came across this puzzler while trying to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66609014/how-should-i-implement-this-struct-default-trait-lifetime).

How / why does this compile:

```rust
#[derive(Debug,Default)]
struct Foo {
    i: i32
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Bar<'a> {
    foo: &'a Foo
}

impl<'a> Default for Bar<'a> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Bar {
            foo: &Foo{ i: 25 }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let bar : Bar = Default::default();
    println!("{:?}", bar);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f5b614c7ffe493035081fd823a3e6e02)

We create an instance of `Bar`, which contains a reference to a `Foo`, but who owns the `Foo`? It was created anonymously within the `default()` function, so I was expecting an error saying that the reference to it outlived its scope.

If I change the `default()` implementation then I get the expected error:

```rust
    fn default() -> Self {
        let foo = Foo{ i: 25 };
        Bar {
            foo: &foo
        }
    }
```

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `foo`
  --> src/main.rs:15:9
   |
15 | /         Bar {
16 | |             foo: &foo
   | |                  ---- `foo` is borrowed here
17 | |         }
   | |_________^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

I read the section in the reference pertaining to [temporary scopes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.48.0/reference/destructors.html#temporary-scopes) - I didn't find any case where the scope of a temporary could extend beyond the scope of a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to [Constant Promotion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.48.0/reference/destructors.html#constant-promotion):

> Promotion of a value expression to a `'static` slot occurs when the expression could be written in a constant, borrowed, and dereferencing that borrow where the expression was originally written, without changing the runtime behavior. That is, the promoted expression can be evaluated at compile-time and the resulting value does not contain [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.48.0/reference/interior-mutability.html) or [destructors](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.48.0/reference/destructors.html) (these properties are determined based on the value where possible, e.g. `&None` always has the type `&'static Option<_>`, as it contains nothing disallowed).