# Why isn't Default::default() a constant function?

Tags: rust, default

As of Rust 1.6, the current trait [`Default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html) is defined as,

```rust
pub trait Default {
    fn default() -> Self;
}
```

Why isn't this though

```rust
pub trait Default {
    const fn default() -> Self;
}
```

Comment: `Default` is older than `const fn`, isn't it? Changing it would be a breaking change if every implementation would then have to be `const`.

Comment: @SebastianRedl it's certainly older than constant functions traits which don't exist yet. But all things are on the table for Rust 2.0. ;)

Comment: Is it guaranteed to be always `const`able, however? Allocations in `const fn` are unstable too, for example, so `<Box<T> as Default>::default` (which is available when `T: Default`) will not yet be `const`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Hard limitation of rustc

This is because currently,

```rust
error[E0379]: functions in traits cannot be declared const
  --> src/main.rs:15:2
   |
15 |     const fn default() -> Self {
   |     ^^^^^ functions in traits cannot be const
```

This is [being worked on GitHub #63065](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/63065). Perhaps there will be a better solution to this problem when functions in traits can be declared `const`.

- If you want to know how to work around this now see [the answer on the question *"Rust: cannot call non-const fn `<Foo as Default>::default` in constants"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72467679/124486)

Comment: The issue you linked is a wrong one. The right issue is probably https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/67792, although we're not sure this is the way forward. Probably the working solution will be some kind of an effect system, currently in planning stage.

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of ways to implement `Default::default` that are not `const`. For example:

```
use rand;

struct MyStruct {
    v: u32
}
impl Default for MyStruct {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self {
            // RNG will never be const!
            v: rand::random()
        }
    }
}
```

Less contrived examples would include referencing global variables, such as cloning an `Arc` of some global default configuration.

Changing `Default::default`, even if supported in rustc, would be an unacceptably breaking change, and arguably undesired.